# Trying to get Taxonomy counts by term/language, including 0 counts

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, taxonomy

On a multilingual Drupal site, I am trying to create a View that lists all the terms for a particular Taxonomy, and include the count of nodes associated with that term, broken down by language. For the most part, it works, except for when I have content for a term in one language, but not another, it doesn't show correctly in that language.

Sample data:
Taxonomy: Education, Food, Travel
Languages: English, Korean

Nodes:

```
Name | Taxonomy | language
Education Test E | Education | en
Education Test E2 | Education | en
Education Test K | Education | ko
Food Test E | Food | en
```

Desired results:

```
Taxonomy | Language | Count
Education | en | 2
Education | ko | 1
Food | en | 0
Food | ko | 1
Travel | en | 0
Travel | ko | 0
```

What I'm getting:

```
Taxonomy | Language | Count
Education | en | 2
Education | ko | 1
Food | ko | 1
Travel | en | 0
Travel | ko | 0
```

In SQL, I've figured out the query I need:

```
SELECT l.language, td.name, COUNT(n.nid) AS Questions
FROM languages l
CROSS JOIN taxonomy_term_data td
LEFT OUTER JOIN field_data_field_qa_topic qat ON td.tid=qat.field_qa_topic_tid AND qat.deleted= '0'
LEFT JOIN node n ON qat.entity_id = n.nid AND n.language=l.language
WHERE td.vid=9
GROUP BY l.language, td.name
ORDER BY td.weight, td.name, l.language;
```

But I can't figure out how to get it working in Views. (And yes, I have the Views Cross Join module installed.)

Another option- I've created this query as a view in MySQL, but can't figure out how to expose the SQL view in Drupal Views.

Either method (creating a Drupal View or exposing the SQL view to Drupal) would be fine at this point- I just want to get it working. Thanks!

EDIT: Just to clarify what I'm trying to achieve, I want a list of ALL terms for this particular taxonomy (so users get a link to the corresponding page) AND a count of existing content pages for each term (including those that have 0). I would prefer to have a filter on just the current user's language, but I can also use it with all the languages and filter out in code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if i misunderstood you, but if the thing you want to achieve is to get the count for the language the current user is using right or the current language the site is using than you must add the Filter Criteria - Content: Language and select the users or sites language.

Or you want to get a data table of all language / content list?

Comment: All- please see the Desired results in the question. I've gone down that route- as soon as I add a filter for the language, it filters out all the 0 counts.